# How to add registry key on Windows CE 5.0 device?

Tags: registry, windows-ce, host, regedit

I've a panel pc which runs Windows CE 5.0. On top of this runs some proprietary runtime.

Due to the specifics of the network, I would like to add a static "host" entry for one IP. I found out that on CE, hosts entries are stored as registry keys (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/199370)

There is no regedit on CE. And .reg files also are not recognized. I read about a "remote registry editor" from Microsoft which seems to come with the CE "Platformbuilder", which I do not have access to.

So, how can I get to add this key to my device's registry?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Remote Registry Editor is part of the Visual Studio Remote Tools. These are available in Visual Studio 2008. You can use this to edit the registry - the Platform Builder isn't necessary.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you. No other, simpler way to just add one key?

Comment: I believe this is the easiest way. There are some regedit like tools that run directly on the device. You need to find one that will run on your device. Try http://www.google.gr/search?q=windows+ce+regedit

Answer (score 1):

This is a great program to edit the registry one Windows CE.

[Simple Listtle Registry Editor](http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2009/07/27/window-ce-simple-little-registry-editor.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Although you can create a .reg file and double click it ([Format](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehall/archive/2005/03/23/401348.aspx)), the best way is to install Embedded C++ on your machine, it's free and has the Remote Registry Editor (and some other nice remote tools).

Comment: While Embedded C++ still works, I recently started using Visual Studio C++ 2008 for Windows CE and really recommend that over eMbedded. It has 90 days free trial - after that I'm not sure of the price, yet. Yes, eMbedded is free.